# Image decoded from Base64 is getting smaller than the normal image. [png]

Tags: android, base64, decode

I can successfully convert the given Base64 string to corresponding image in Android.
To test this scenario in my app, I took one image from my drawable folder and convert it into its corresponding Base64 string using this website : [Motobit.com](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp?charset=iso-8859-1&acharset=). The image that I gave on this website was this:
[image]

Its 23X25 pixels in dimension and 46.3KB in size.
Using below code in my Android I am converting this image's Base64 into Image as follows:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(tabData.getString("TabIconImageData"), Base64.DEFAULT);
                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new Options();
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500);
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length,options);
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;
    
            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    
                // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
                // width
                final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                        / (float) reqHeight);
                final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    
                // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
                // guarantee
                // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
                // requested height and width.
                inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
            }
    
            return inSampleSize;
        }
```

The Base64 string is getting converted successfully in image, but it looks nealy half in the size than of its original image. I want the image of its original size and also in PNG format.
Please guide me for this to resolve.

Comment: Have you checked what is returned by calculateInSampleSize?

Comment: @Apfelsaft : No, I got this function from Android developer website to optimize the bitmap object

Comment: @Apfelsaft : I debugged my app and found that calculateInSampleSize is returning 1. What does this mean?

Comment: That means that calculateInSampleSize is not the source of your problem. options.inSampleSize=1 means, that the image is not scaled while reading. options.inSampleSize=2 would reduce the image size by one half.

Comment: Although it has nothing to do with your problem, I just want to make sure that you know what calculateInSampleSize is doing. In your current implementation, evey image bigger than 500x500 is scaled down to the nearest size smaller than 500x500.

Comment: @Apfelsaft : So how this can be resolved? Should I multiply it to (1/2) ?

Comment: Your code: options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500) Change 500 to whatever you want to be the maximum widht and height. But bigger images will consume more heap memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap btm = decodeBase64("Base64 String");
        Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btm, btm.getWidth(), btm.getHeight(), false);
        company_logo.setImageBitmap(bt);
```

and this

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```

Comment: Its giving me still the same result.. :(

Comment: Still the same result dude, Even I tried the code by fully uninstalling the app and then installing it again..

Comment: Hey dude, the following worked for me: Thanks for your help      `Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btm, 50, 50, false);`

Comment: But still I am losing some details of the original image. i.e. colors and its appearance